# What is the default TLS version used by Spring restTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, tls1.2

We have been asked to invoke a specific rest service with BASIC AUTHENTICATION over HTTPS (TLS 1.2). I am using Spring restTemplate to invoke this service.

If it is less than TLSv1.2, I can use HTTP client to enforce 1.2. But How do I check what TLS version is being used by restTemplate?

Comment: It's not up to the template, or Spring. It is determined by Java. If not configured it will be determined by the Java version. And of course by what the peer supports: it's negotiated.

Comment: This questions ask for how to enforce a specific TLS-version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161542/how-to-enforce-tls1-2-to-rest-client-using-rest-template and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619871/access-https-rest-service-using-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided in the comment by @ejp is correct:

> It's not up to the template, or Spring. It is determined by Java. If not configured it will be determined by the Java version. And of course by what the peer supports: it's negotiated.