# Java 8 How to make sure our code checks the full certificate chain?

Tags: java, ssl, resttemplate

I have Spring Boot 1.5 app which is setting up a connection with some Web Services. In all the cases, these are TLS 1.2 connections. I run my app passing this JVM params:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${KEYSTORE} \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${KEYSTORE_PW} -> password
```

The javax.net.ssl.keyStore is just a jks file with a single certificate in it.

I need to answer this question: when setting up the TLS connection, how can I know if am I checking the full certificate chain? Or just the root certificate? Is it just depends on the CA I have in each of my certificates contained in my trust store?

I use RestTemplate to make the connections:

```
ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, T.class);
```

My RestTemplate instance has nothing fancy, this is how I build it:

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

Thanks all.

UPDATE Feb 14 2019

I wanted to clarify something. I am 100% sure my code uses TLS 1.2. If I remove my certs from my key store, then all the calls start to fail complaining with SSL Exceptions.

The certificate chain from the Service I'm calling consists on a leaf certificate and an intermediate certificate. They said they will update only the leaf certificate, and they said this:

*"If client systems trust VendorX-issued certificates with
the complete chain, then the new Leaf Certificate will need to be updated."*

The part that confuses me is "the complete chain". What does that mean? Does it mean that you can either validate a part of the chain or the full chain?

Answer (score -1):

check [Michal Foksa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4607349/michal-foksa)'s answer here. it should be a starting point for you: [How to enforce TLS1.2 to Rest client using Rest Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161542/how-to-enforce-tls1-2-to-rest-client-using-rest-template)

Comment: I know already my Rest Template checks certificates, because if I remove my certs from my keystore then the calls are rejected. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: Although links can be helpful, anwers must be self-contained. Please read: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)